# How to convert timestamp that is in string to minutes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have a timestamp column that is in string but i want to convert it to minutes. I tried several things but does not work as i intended. How can i achieve this.

```
Timestamp         Time(In Mins)
1650662101985      34
1650661692003      42


 df["Timestamp"] = df["Timestamp"].apply(lambda x: str(int(x/(1000*60)) % 60))
```

This code give me the minutes but does not match that timestamp.

Comment: Please read about [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Comment: Can you give us any more context on what this "Timestamp" column means? It's not Unix time, since there are too many characters in the it.

Comment: What minutes? The minutes of the time of these timestamps? The total minutes since a reference? What format is it?

Comment: yes minutes of this timestamps

Comment: You didn't answer my questions with clarity... "minutes of a timestamp" doesn't make sense. Can you give the exact datetime corresponding to `1650662101985`? Is the provided output correct? Please answer **all** questions with clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to choose the correct unit:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'],unit='ms')
```

Then extract the minutes with .dt.minute

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'],unit='ms').dt.minute
```